# C getchar() doesn't wait for input/ conditional loop doesn't int

Tags: c, loops, io, console

I am trying to add a feature to my C console application calculator that prompts the user to decide whether they want to perform another calculation using: `y` or `n`, but in testing, `getchar()` refuses to wait for input and the program proceeds as though it has received valid input.  The following is a minimal example of the feature:

```
main()
{
    char newCalculation;

    do{
        lengthFormula(); /* main calculation formula */
        printf("Would you like to do another calculation? (Y/N)");
        newCalculation = getchar();

    }while(tolower( newCalculation ) == 'y');

    if(tolower(newCalculation) == 'n'){
        exitProgram(); /* exit the program */
    }

    while(tolower(newCalculation) != 'n' && tolower(newCalculation) != 'y'){
        printf("This is not a valid response.\n Please enter \"Y\" 
                if you want to do another calculation, 
                or enter \"N\" to exit.\n");
        newCalculation = getchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, the program does not wait for input after:

`Would you like to do another calculation? (Y/N)`

, but instead proceeds as though it has received invalid input.  The result is that it spits out the prompt and the invalid input notice one after the other without a space:

`Would you like to do another calculation? (Y/N)`

`This is not a valid response.`

`Please enter \"Y\" if you want to do another calculation, or enter \"N\" to exit.`

If I enter a `"y"` after this, `main()` returns `0` and the program terminates.

Is someone able to see where I went wrong here?
Why won't the console wait for input at `getchar()`?
Why does valid input terminate the program after the first invalid response?

P.S.: Please don't tell me to "read a book" or shoo me away to Dennis Ritchie or one of the previous SO discussions on input.  I've been poring over Richie's discussion of I/O, as well as similar texts from Lynda.com and Wiley, and none of the previous "it won't wait for input" posts addresses my issue as far as I can tell.

@simplicisveritatis Here is the modification of your code that I tried. Still have the same getchar issues.

```
int main(void)
{
    /* local variable declaration */
    char newCalculation = 'y';

    /* main function */
    /*if(tolower( newCalculation ) == 'y')
    {
        lengthFormula(newCalculation);
    }*/
    do
    {
        lengthFormula();

        printf("Would you like to do another calculation? (Y/N)");
        newCalculation = getchar();

        if( tolower( newCalculation ) == 'n' )
        {
            exitProgram();
        }

        while( tolower( newCalculation ) != 'n' && tolower( newCalculation ) != 'y' )
        {
            printf("This is not a valid response.\n Please enter \"Y\" if you want to do another calculation, or enter \"N\" to exit.\n");
            newCalculation = getchar();
        }
    }while( tolower( newCalculation ) == 'y' );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Having made the correction offered by @user3121023, the program exits after an incorrect entry is re-entered, because there is no loop to make it start over. If you indent/align the code properly, this will be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of problems:
main should be:

```
int main(void){return 0;}
```

You need to cast getchar (read about getchar) and should be:

```
newCalculation = (char)getchar();
```

Your approach on do{}while; + while{} is also wrong used.

Try the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int     validate;
    char    menu_choice;
    validate = 0;

    do{
        printf("Would you like another go?(y/n):\t" );

        if(scanf(" %c", &menu_choice ) == 1){
            if((menu_choice=='y') || (menu_choice=='Y')){
                printf("You choosed Yes\n\n\n");
                validate = 1;
            }else if((menu_choice=='n') || (menu_choice=='N')){
                printf("You choosed No\n\n\n");
                validate = 2;
            }else{
                printf("Wrong Input.\n\n\n");
                validate = 0;
            }
        }
    }while( validate == 0 || validate == 1);

    printf("Goodbye\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "You need to cast getchar" is questionable advice.  When using `getchar()`, the return value should be saved as an `int` so code may discern 1 of 256 characters or `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

Include your three cases: *exit condition*, *wrong input* and *calculate* within the `while` loop:

```
main(){
do{
    printf("Would you like to do another calculation? (Y/N)");
    // get input
    char newCalculation;
    newCalculation = getchar();

    // exit condition
    if(tolower(newCalculation) == 'n'){
        exitProgram(); /* exit the program */
    }
    // wrong input condition
    else if(tolower(newCalculation) != 'n' && tolower(newCalculation) != 'y'){
        printf("This is not a valid response.\n Please enter \"Y\" 
            if you want to do another calculation, 
            or enter \"N\" to exit.\n");
       // you should clear the input stream from the wrong input
    } 
    else{
        // calculate  
        lengthFormula();  
     }
}while(tolower(newCalculation) == 'y');

return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I run that version of 'main()', the first input prompt is '"Would you like to do another calculation? (Y/N)"' and then when I input a 'y', 'main()' returns '0' and terminates.  I would like the program to call 'lengthFormula()' once on startup before printing the 'another calculation?'  prompt, and I would like input of 'y' to call 'lengthFormula() again.  Check above for what I tried.  I have the same problem as I did initially.

Comment: @Nathaniel Lindsey there is no point in calling `lengthFormula()` without an input value. What is your `lengthFormula()` returning ?

Answer (score 0):

> Why won't the console wait for input at getchar()?

Most probably, your function `lengthFormula()` reads input (e. g. by using `scanf()` or whatever), but doesn't read the line ending character `\n` from the input buffer. Then after returning from `lengthFormula()`, the `getchar()` has to read remaining content from the input buffer rather than requesting fresh input.

> Why does valid input terminate the program after the first invalid
>   response?

That's because your

```
    while(tolower(newCalculation) != 'n' && tolower(newCalculation) != 'y')
```

does the same after a response of `y` as after a response of `n` - it leaves the loop and gets to the following

```
    return 0;
```